# C# WPF Datagrid binding in xaml to string array

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I try to bind a string array to a Datagrid column. I've got a int variable but I want to show a string value. So my idea is to bind a string array and use the int value as index.

```
public class TestStep : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public int Mode { get; set; }

    public string[] ModeName { get; set; } = { "name1", "name2" };
}
```

So the XAML I use is:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestStep , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode ID" Binding="{Binding Mode }" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode ID Name" Binding="{Binding ModeName[0]}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode ID Name" Binding="{Binding ModeName[Mode]}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

If I use  `Binding="{Binding ModeName[0]}"` I get the correct value in the datagrid

If I use `Binding="{Binding ModeName]Mode]}` I get a Binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''String[]' (HashCode=62367561)'.
> BindingExpression:Path=ModeName[{1}]; DataItem='TestStep' (HashCode=4862753); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Why can't I resolute the variable Mode in the `[]`Block?

Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I resolve the variable Mode in the [] Block?

Binding path is not dynamic. `ModeName[Mode]` in xaml is interpreted as `ModeName["Mode"]` in c# (string indexer).

but you can create a special property using both ModeName and Mode, and bind to it:

```
public class TestStep : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public int Mode { get; set; }

    public string[] ModeName { get; set; } = { "name1", "name2" };

    public string CurrentModeName
    { 
         get { return ModeName[Mode]; }
         set { ModeName[Mode] = value; }
    }
}
```

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestStep}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode ID" Binding="{Binding Mode}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode ID Name" Binding="{Binding ModeName[0]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode ID Name" Binding="{Binding CurrentModeName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```